# wp_localize_script() works only on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to work with leafletjs in a my wordpress pluglin. Here is the code where i register script.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ea_map_load_scripts' );
function ea_map_load_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'ea_map_leaflet_js', plugins_url('js/leaflet.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_register_script( 'ea_map_js', plugins_url('js/map.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false,true);
    //                                                                                          ^^
    //I need to use this parameter otherwhise the leafletjs map is not charged------------------|
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ea_map_leaflet_js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ea_map_js' );
    ...
}
```

Here by do_action() on my theme, i call that function where i try to pass some php variable to my javascript plugin:

```
add_action('wp_ea_map','wp_ea_map');
function wp_ea_map() {
    $ea_params = Array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'latitudine' => 'xx.xxx',
        'longitudine' => '-xx.xxx',
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'ea_map_js', 'marker', $map_params );
}
```

The problem is that the same code whit the same database, on my localhost works well but on the live server marker variable is not setted. Here the js code where i use the passed variable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var map = L.map('map').setView([marker.latitudine, marker.longitudine], 11);
    ....
});
```

And yes, i'am sure that i have the same code in both server and that there is no cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's a time problem . When the 'ea_map_js' is loaded the action 'wp_ea_map' is not already called.

I have found a solution that works on the live server too, moving the wp_localize_script function after wp_enqueue_script( 'ea_map_js' ) inside ea_map_load_scripts(). The code now look like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ea_map_load_scripts' );
function ea_map_load_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'ea_map_leaflet_js', plugins_url('js/leaflet.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false,true);
    wp_register_script( 'ea_map_js', plugins_url('js/map.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false,true);

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ea_map_leaflet_js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ea_map_js' );

    $ea_params = Array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'latitudine' => 'xx.xxx',
       'longitudine' => '-xx.xxx',
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'ea_map_js', 'marker', $map_params );
    ...
}
```

I have tryed another solution using another hook pasting the variable in the code by an echo:

```
add_action('wp_head','wp_baro');
function wp_baro(){
   $post_id = get_the_ID();

   echo '<script>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            var marker = {  
                "id" : "'.$post_id.'",
                "latitudine" : "'.xx.xxxx.'",
                "longitudine" : "'.yy.yyyy.'"};
        /* ]]> */
        </script>';
}
```